# How to display List<BufferedImage>images in html page using AngularJS get api

Tags: html, angularjs, spring, spring-boot

i have api which is return List. i need to fetch these details in Using AngularJS $Http.Get api and need to display those images in HTML page.

## Spring side GET APi:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/imageDisplay", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public List<BuffeedImage> showImage()
            throws ServletException, IOException {
}
```

can you any one help me in this?

Comment: ensure your url is working and returning the list then check at the http service of angularjs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http